# How to write to a file that writes to a file in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I am working on writing to a file in Batch, what I'm writing to ALSO will be  written to a file, and that's not working in Batch.

Here's my script:

```
@echo off
set FILENAME=work.bat
echo @echo off >>%FILENAME%
echo set FILENAME2=work2.bat >>%FILENAME%

echo echo @echo off >>%FILENAME2% >>%FILENAME%
echo echo Testing script >>%FILENAME2% >>%FILENAME%
echo echo Testing script again >>%FILENAME2% >>%FILENAME%
echo echo Testing script yet again >>%FILENAME2% >>%FILENAME%
echo echo Okay done testing >>%FILENAME2% >>%FILENAME%
echo echo pause >>%FILENAME2% >>%FILENAME%
echo pause >>%FILENAME%
pause
```

This file is writing to %FILENAME% which writes to %FILENAME2%, but it crashes while writing everything in the file. It's not that it's not called, but it crashes because it doesn't understand it.

EDIT: Sorry, I'm tired and forgot to add required information... I am working on writing a batch file in batch that writes to a file pretty much. However, it looks like it gets confused because there are two >>. I forgot to add my updated code to this, though, and now I have. It crashes when it gets to the first echo echo.

I see why it wouldn't work, but I've tried so many solutions and none of them work! I'm surprised I can't find a solution, I would appreciate it a lot if I could get a solution.

Comment: read about *quoting* and *escaping* regarding batch files

Comment: @hoijui I looked that up on Google and really didn't find anything interesting for my case. Care to explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop

```
@echo off
echo work.bat > list.txt
echo work2.bat >> list.txt
for /f %%i in (list.txt) do call :write %%i
del list.txt

:write
echo echo Testing script >>%1
echo echo Testing script again >>%1
echo echo Testing script yet again >>%1
echo echo Okay done testing >>%1
```

---

after your comment please try

```
@echo off
set FILENAME=work.bat
set FILENAME2=work2.bat

echo @echo off ^>^>%FILENAME2% >>%FILENAME%
echo echo Testing script ^>^>%FILENAME2% >>%FILENAME%
echo echo Testing script again ^>^>%FILENAME2% >>%FILENAME%
echo echo Testing script yet again ^>^>%FILENAME2% >>%FILENAME%
echo echo Okay done testing ^>^>%FILENAME2% >>%FILENAME%
```

Comment: Interesting script, but I don't mean for the main file to write both of the files when you run it. I mean that you run the main file and then it writes work.bat, and then when you run work.bat it will generate work2.bat.